# template functions in nested template classes

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes

I'm experiencing a problem in some code I've been working on. Here is the most simplified version of it I could create:

```
template <class A>
class Outer {
public:
    template <class B>
    class Inner {
    public:
        template <class C>
        void foo(Outer<C>::Inner<C> innerC) { }
    };

    Inner<A> inner;
};

class X {};
class Y {};

int main() {
    Outer<X> outerX;
    Outer<Y> outerY;
    outerX.foo<Y>(outerY.inner);
}
```

The error is:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ">" token
```

and is triggered at compiletime at the declaration of `void foo`. What is incorrect about my code that is making this happen?

In words, what I am trying to do is have the nested class be able to take in a nested class with any template type - but of course the nested class's template type depends on the outer class's template type, so I use the `::` syntax, but that gives an error.

I understand that what I'm trying to do here might not be a good practice, but the  purpose of this question is to understand template syntax better.

Comment: There is no conversion from `1` to `Inner<C>`

Comment: More than that, there's no way for `C` to be deduced. Can you show us an example of the case that works?

Comment: I'm assuming your actual usage is not `Inner<A>`, otherwise you wouldn't need to template the inner class to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no conversion from `1` to `Inner<C>`. Is that an error in your reduced test case, or is it supposed to be:

```
template <class C>
void foo(C innerC) { }
```

**Update:** After the code was fixed, it can be seen that the problem is the lack of `template` before `Inner<C>`. Otherwise the compiler will assume that `Inner` is a value.

```
template <class C>
void foo(Outer<C>::template Inner<C> innerC) { }
```

Comment: That's an error in my reduced test case. I'll update the OP asap.

Comment: Have not made the fix - had to go yesterday, and I'm now working on isolating the issue properly. Will update shortly.

Comment: Ok I've updated the code and error. Hopefully it is more helpful. Any ideas?

Comment: That one is easy, you would need `Outer<C>::template Inner<C>`

Comment: Awesome. Can you explain how exactly that works and why that is necessary? You say "otherwise the compiler will assume that Inner is a value", which is cool, but how do I know when I need to use this `template` syntax?

Comment: Its equivalent to `typename`, there is ton of information available on the site on when to use it. Basically, when inside a template you access something from another template the compiler can't instantiate that inner class so it doesn't know if inner members are values or types. It assumes by default they are all values, you need to use `typename` or `template` to let the compiler know you are actually referring to a type or a template type.